# Connection Broken Error with C3P0 ,Azure SQL, Hibernate and Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, azure-sql-database, c3p0

We are using JAVA, Hibernate, C3P0 connection pool, and database Azure SQL in our application. While in the middle of large processing, we are seeing database connection error with the below exception.
We are using Hibernate sessions for transaction management. We are unable to find any means of retrying the connection to the database as Hibernate session abstracts connection details.

- hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 0
- hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay = 3000
- hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure = false

The exception is as below :

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The connection is broken and recovery is not possible. The connection is marked by the server as unrecoverable. No attempt was made to restore the connection.
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.zenoptics.hibernate.LCatalogCategoriesTreeDAO.findByProperty(LCatalogCategoriesTreeDAO.java:89)
    at com.zenoptics.hibernate.LCatalogCategoriesTreeDAO.findByParentCategoryId(LCatalogCategoriesTreeDAO.java:109)
    at com.zenoptics.api.util.ExtractorsUtil.generateJsonStructureFromCategoryTree(ExtractorsUtil.java:1826)
    at com.zenoptics.api.core.TableauAPIExtractor.begin(TableauAPIExtractor.java:3468)
    at com.zenoptics.api.core.MainJob.execute(MainJob.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is broken and recovery is not possible. The connection is marked by the server as unrecoverable. No attempt was made to restore the connection.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3754)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:456)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1471)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
```

This error is very much consistent and happeing somewhere in the long running batch process, and the retry logs configured with the hibernate C3P0 is not helping though it is set to indefinite retry

- hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 0

Here what we wanted to achiev is, in the broken connection case, our application should retry indefinitely and pick up the healthy connection after a while and continue doing its own thing.

Any help would be really appreciated!

the dependencies we use are..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        
 </dependency>
```